# Google app engine cronjob 10 minitues limitation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I have deployed & Scheduled  Fb data collection java web application on GAE using cron.xml.
my application is collecting data and loading data to google cloud storage.

One limitation of GAE which I found while implementing is the application window will be active  through cron job only for 10 minutes.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

Data collection process requires more than 10 minutes to collect complete data.

please suggest me some alternative options.and reference links to increase 10 minutes time limit.

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a B-type instance with Basic Scaling for your cron job. It does not have a 10 minute limit:

[App Engine Modules in Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)

Comment: Or use task queues which allows for a more robust implementation (process by chunks, retry on error etc)

Comment: @Zig: Tasks have the same time limitations based on their target. If this job cannot be split into small tasks that can run on an F-instance, then it should target a B-instance. I agree, however, that every job that can be split should be split using tasks.

Comment: Yes, i was assuming it can be split.

Comment: i have used default push Queues . by using queue.add(withurl("")) method added data collection process to taskQueues and deployed it to GAE. in error logs it is showing post http/1.1 200 error continuously .and not loading any data to GCS. please help me on solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mapreduce library (in this case for map only stage) and provide your own custom Input (there is already an output that can write to GCS). The mapreduce library is using the taskqueus as well but it slices its work into as many tasks as needed.